# what is fastest as a django production server : twisted.web2 vs. apache mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, twisted, mod-wsgi

i want to deploy my django project, what is best (on performance) of these 2 deployment methodologies:

1. [Django-On-Twisted](http://code.google.com/p/django-on-twisted/)
2. apache mod_wsgi

i knew that mod_wsgi was recommended by django developers but i feel twisted is more efficient when running multiple django instance.

Comment: The web serving mechanism is nearly never the bottleneck, why are you presuming it is and trying to prematurely optimize things?

Comment: `but i feel twisted is more efficient when running multiple django instance`: Care to elaborate on "feel", "more", "efficient" and "multiple django instance"? Have you run any benchmarks to confirm your feelings?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As has been said, the server deployment setup won't be the bottleneck at this stage, however I still feel there's definitely value in picking and learning something now which you're more likely to continue using in future.

This recent benchmark generated a lot of discussion:

http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers

Read the comments as well as the numbers in order to get a feel for how benchmarks never show the full picture.

For a web server Nginx is a no brainer IMO.

For a WSGI server I like uWSGI because it seems performant and I get the feeling it has much of the community behind it.  uwsgi is well supported by Nginx.

Hope that helps :> Let us know what you go for.

Comment: yes, you help me alot. thank you very much. I read about uwsgi and instantly I fall in love with it. now i am installing it on my computer to see what it can do... the good news is that they said you can control it on your django project through a simple admin interface [uwsgi_admin]. so, it may be the right choice for me.